# ComboBox with manual text input to help user select item in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, combobox, xamarin.forms

User need to select value from a list (huge list).

For examle:

- Foo
- Snack
- StackOverflow
- Stop

I think about something like ComboBox with manual text input.

What I mean. User select this control and start typing "st" - list of selectable items shortens to:

- StackOverflow
- Stop

How to declare such control?

Comment: IMHO better approach is to use single textbox and listview. In textbox, you can handle ValueChanged event and filter ItemsSource of the listview. Other way you must create your own control for each implemented platform which is hell of a work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Xamarin Android I think it is [Autocomplete Text Input](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/controls/autocomplete_text_view/add_an_autocomplete_text_input/)